# Updating a user concurrently in mongoose using model.save() throws error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting a mongoose error when I attempt to update a user field multiple times.
What I want to achieve is to update that user based on some conditions after making an API call to an external resource.
From what I observe, I am hitting both conditions at the same time in the `processUser()` function
hence, `user.save()` is getting called almost concurrently and mongoose is not happy about that throwing me this error:

`MongooseError [ParallelSaveError]: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 5ea1c634c5d4455d76fa4996`

I know am guilty and my code is the culprit here because I am a novice. But is there any way I can achieve my desired result without hitting this error? Thanks.

```
function getLikes(){
    var users = [user1, user2, ...userN]

    users.forEach((user) => {
        processUser(user)
    })
}

async function processUser(user){
    var result = await makeAPICall(user.url)
    // I want to update the user based on the returned value from this call
    // I am updating the user using `mongoose save()`

    if (result === someCondition) {
        user.meta.likes += 1
        user.markModified("meta.likes")

        try {
            await user.save()
            return
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return
        }
    } else {
        user.meta.likes -= 1
        user.markModified("meta.likes")

        try {
            await user.save()
            return
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return
        }
    }
}

setInterval(getLikes, 2000)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the try/catch block outside the conditional? i.e. process all of the modifications before saving.

Comment: I just did so, the error remains the same. Interestingly, I am getting half of the results correct and the remaining half throwing the `Can't save error`. My guess is that they are still running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that need to be addressed in your code.

1) processUser is an asynchronous function. `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't respect asynchronous functions as documented [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

2) setInterval doesn't respect the return value of your function as documented [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), therefore passing a function that returns a promise (async/await) will not behave as intended.

3) setInterval shouldn't be used with functions that could potentially take longer to run than your interval as documented [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) in the `Usage Section` near the bottom of the page.

Hitting an external api for every user every 2 seconds and reacting to the result is going to be problematic under the best of circumstances. I would start by asking myself if this is absolutely the **only** way to achieve my overall goal.

If it **is** the only way, you'll probably want to implement your solution using the recursive `setTimeout()` mentioned at the link in #2 above, or perhaps using an async version of `setInterval()` [there's one on npm here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-interval-async)

Comment: your answer helps. The `set-interval-async` package helps. `Hitting an external api for every user every 2 seconds`. It's actually not 2 seconds, I only made that value up to illustrate how fast the function runs. Overall, your recommendation works just fine, :)